# Azure ADF Salesforce connector Copy Activity failing with HybridDeliveryException

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to load the data from Salesforce table to ADLS path. To perform this I'm using SOQL formatted query in the source dataset(Salesforce) of ADF pipeline copy activity. Sample below.

**Select distinct `col1`, `col2`, `col3`....... from table**

This pipeline is working for all the tables except two table where it is failing with HybridDeliveryException (Exact error below)

I also tried pulling only 10 rows. still no luck. But for the same table is working without any issues by selecting all columns -> **select * from table**

Any suggestions greatly appreciated

***Error:***
Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=UserErrorOdbcOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.   ,Message=ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][DSI] (20051) Internal error using swap file "D:\Users_azbatchtask_410\AppData\Local\Temp\a60f5b9a-da9c-47b3-9d03-14d64bf44dce.tmp" in "Simba::DSI::DiskSwapDevice::DoFlushBlock": "[Microsoft][Support] (40635) Simba::Support::BinaryFile: Write of 57168 bytes on file "D:\Users_azbatchtask_410\AppData\Local\Temp\a60f5b9a-da9c-47b3-9d03-14d64bf44dce.tmp" failed: No space left on device".,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.Odbc.OdbcConnector,''Type=System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException,Message=ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][DSI] (20051) Internal error using swap file "D:\Users_azbatchtask_410\AppData\Local\Temp\a60f5b9a-da9c-47b3-9d03-14d64bf44dce.tmp" in "Simba::DSI::DiskSwapDevice::DoFlushBlock": "[Microsoft][Support] (40635) Simba::Support::BinaryFile: Write of 57168 bytes on file "D:\Users_azbatchtask_410\AppData\Local\Temp\a60f5b9a-da9c-47b3-9d03-14d64bf44dce.tmp" failed: No space left on device".,Source=Microsoft Salesforce ODBC Driver,'

Answer (score 0):

This might not be a complete answer but this be helpful for someone as a workaround.

I ran some more tests today and when I remove the key word "distinct" in the SOQL statement, the query is working fine and no exceptions this time.

Seems like that the issue is occurring with only specific large tables.

But the SOQL with **distinct** (**Select distinct col1, col2, col3.......**) is working fine for other smaller tables.